# Android. Upgrading gradle from gradle-4.10.2 to gradle 5.+ causes some dependencies to be missing at compile time

Tags: android, gradle

My project has a dependency in a Android library which contains different modules (App module with different sub-modules)

When I upgrade from 4.10 to 5+, some dependencies in my project are missing at compile time.

I tried to use API, but it does not make any difference

Any ideas would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that in the chan of transitive dependencies, you were relying on dependencies with a `runtime` scope in their Maven metadata.

As of Gradle 5.0, these dependencies are no longer available at compile time, to better respect their metadata semantic.

One way of confirming that is to run `./gradle <project>:dependencies --configuration compileClasspath` on your affected `project` (remove if this concerns the root project) and compare the output with Gradle 4.10 and 5.+.

You can also have a look at [the migration notes](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html#rel5.0:pom_compile_runtime_separation) on this topic